# Set default values of year and month using django-yearmonth-widget

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

How to set default value using django-yearmonth-widget for year as current year and month as month_name-1

Forms

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField(required=True,widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':True}), label='Select Files')
    file_remote = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':True}), required=False)
    class Meta():
        model = FileUpload
        fields= ('file_upload_datetime','file','file_remote')
        widgets = {
            'file_upload_datetime': DjangoYearMonthWidget(),
            'file_remote':forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

Models

```
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
    file_remote = models.FileField(upload_to=RetailFormsConfig.remote_folder, storage=upload_storage, blank=True)
    file_upload_datetime = models.DateField()
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, i tired to set default value using https://pypi.org/project/django-yearmonth-widget/ but seems DjangoYearMonthWidget() does not accept default attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the default values using javascript by finding the classes

```
current_date = new Date();
      $("select.django-yearmonth-widget-year-selector")
        .val(current_date.getFullYear())
        .change();
      $("select.django-yearmonth-widget-month-selector")
        .val(current_date.getMonth()) //month starting from 0
        .change();
```